# Setting the output value of a dropdown based on the selected item in another dropdown in Livecycle

Tags: livecycle, livecycle-designer, xfa

I'm attempting to set the **formattedValue** of dropdown B based on the **rawValue** selected in dropdown A on an Adobe Livecycle form. Then I wish to export the **rawValue** from dropdown B

Dropdown A has these formattedValues (just one column of data):

- Apple
- Banana
- Cucumber
- Orange

Dropdown B has these formattedValues and rawValues:

- Apple (rawValue: A)
- Banana (rawValue: B)
- Cucumber (rawValue: C)
- Orange: (rawValue: A)

My change event for dropdown A is as follows:

```
myForm.#subform[0].dropdowna::change - (JavaScript, client)

dropdownb.formattedValue = xfa.event.newText;
```

Visibly this works fine, and dropdown B shows the same value as dropdown A. However when I export the data, dropdown B's value is the formattedValue rather than the rawValue. I.e. it is outputting 'Cucumber' instead of C.

Anyone know how I can get dropdown B to output the rawValues instead please?

Comment: Are the items in your dropdowns identical? By this i mean, same number of elements with the same order.

Comment: can you try `dropdownb.execEvent("exit")` or `dropdownb.execEvent("change")` to commit the values?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the rawValue of dropdownB in js with `dropdownb.boundItem(xfa.event.newText);`. Don't know if that will help...